# Ansible - Loop based on dict with stat not working

Tags: ansible

I'm currently creating a possibility to auto-obtain a Letsencrypt certificate using my ansible-playbook.

I'd like to check if the /etc/letsencrypt/domain.tld directory exists, when it doesn't, I need to obtain a certificate.

```
---
- name: LETSENCRYPT | Checking for existing certificates
  stat:
    path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ item.value.server_name }}
  register: le_cert_exists
  with_dict: "{{ sites }}"
  when: item.value.letsencrypt | default(false) | bool

- name: DEBUG | Output result of le cert exists
  debug:
    var: le_cert_exists

- name: LETSENCRYPT | Output sites that need a new certificate
  debug:
    msg: Obtain certificate here
    var: item.item
  with_items: le_cert_exists.results
  when: item.stat.exists is defined and not item.stat.exists
```

So far it is working, except for the last function. The last task just keeps getting skipped or fails with the following error:

```
fatal: [-]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.stat.exists is defined and not item.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.stat.exists is defined and not item.stat.exists): 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/path/to/main.yml': line 13, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: LETSENCRYPT | Output sites that need a new certificate\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Does anyone has an example of how this could be done easily?

I just need to execute a command when a directory does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `with_items: le_cert_exists.results` is wrong,
this `with_items: "{{ le_cert_exists.results }}"` is correct.